# Adding axis labels to a subfig with hinton diagrams in matplotlib without ruining it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found this example on how to do a hinton diagram with matplotlib: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/HintonDiagrams.

I needed multiple diagrams and a yaxis with labels on the ticks so I rewrote it like so

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as N

def hintonForTwo(W1, W2, maxWeight=None):

    height, width = W1.shape
    if not maxWeight:
        maxWeight = 2**N.ceil(N.log(N.max(N.abs(W1)))/N.log(2))

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

    hintonSubPlot(ax1, W1, maxWeight)
    ax1.set_yticks(N.arange(height))
    # the input matrices will have row height of 7
    # and years 1981, 1986... up to 2011 are supposed to be the ytick labels
    ax1.set_yticklabels(tuple(range(1981,2012,5)))
    ax1.set_aspect('equal')
    ax1.set_axis_off()
    hintonSubPlot(ax2, W2, maxWeight)
    return fig, ax1, ax2

def hintonSubPlot(F, W, maxWeight):
    height, width = W.shape
    F.fill(N.array([0,width,width,0]),N.array([0,0,height,height]),'white')

    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):
                _x = x+1
            _y = y+1
            w = W[y,x]
            if w > 0:
                _blobAlt(F, _x - 0.5, height - _y + 0.5, min(1,w/maxWeight),'black')
            elif w < 0:
                _blobAlt(F, _x - 0.5, height - _y + 0.5, min(1,-w/maxWeight),'gray')
    return F

def _blobAlt(F, x,y,area,colour):
    hs = N.sqrt(area) / 2
    xcorners = N.array([x - hs, x + hs, x + hs, x - hs])
    ycorners = N.array([y - hs, y - hs, y + hs, y + hs])
    F.fill(xcorners, ycorners, colour, edgecolor=colour)

dim = (7,50)
X1 = N.ones(dim) * N.nan
X2 = N.ones(dim) * N.nan

rm = N.random.random(dim)
X1[rm > 2.0/3] = 1
X1[rm < 1.0/3] = -1

rm = N.random.random(dim)
X2[rm > 2.0/3] = 1
X2[rm < 1.0/3] = -1

f, a, b = hintonForTwo(X1, X2)
f.savefig('tmp.png')
```

But there are several problems with this that I can't fix:

1. If do ax1.set_axis_off(), I can't get any ytick labels
2. If leave the axes on, I get large blank rectangles around the bottom subfig
3. Even if the set the axes off, there's a large gap between the upper subfig and the bottom subfig that I can't narrow

So how do I get ytick labels but without the large white rectangles around the subfigs and without the big gap between top and bottom?

Comment: your code is incomplete so that it is not posible to reproduce your figure and try to give you a tested solution

Comment: @joaquin I've added code so that it is now possible to copy/paste and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still incomplete. However, if you just want to adjust the spacing between subplots, remove some levels selectively, you may try:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p


fig = p.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.145, bottom=0.13, right=.87, top=.975, wspace=.18, hspace=.10)

x=np.arange(1,10,0.01)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x,np.sin(x),'ro')
ax1.set_ylabel('sin(x)')

ax2=fig.add_subplot(212,sharex=ax1,sharey=ax1)
ax2.plot(x,np.cos(x),'bs')
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('cos(x)')

for label in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_visible(False)

p.show()
```

[image: Plot]